# Tab Bar Items are getting dragged out

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Tab bar Controller as my app's home page with 4 tab bar items. So If I go inside an viewController where bottom bar will be hidden and come back, the 4 tab bar items gets dragged out for one second and come to its original position. I am facing this bug and to solve this I used

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
```

How to solve this Issue? I will try to add the screenshots, but the problem is it happens for only one second I couldn't able to screenshot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in iOS. It should be fixed in the latest beta. In the meantime you can try to disable translucency for the tabbar. It means a little change in the UI but it works around this bug

```
tabBar.isTranslucent = false
```

EDIT: it seems to be fixed in yesterday released iOS 12.1.1

Comment: Thanks. Is it happening for all the apps? Can you give me the link for that bug reference?

Comment: Well I haven't found a radar with any reactions but I my apps all worked fine on 12.0, then had this bug on 12.1 and now are again ok without any updates so I assume so.